# Limit of a sequence implies limit of its infimum?

Tags: probability

I would like to ask:
if $ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}  P{(|\frac {S_n}{n} - 1|>\epsilon)} = 0 $ with any $\epsilon$ that is arbitrarily small, then the following thing holds:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} P\left(\frac {S_n}n  = 1\right) = 1
$$
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for that, @Micheal Hardy. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is true that no matter how small $\varepsilon$ is, you have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr\left( \left| \frac {S_n} n - 1 \right| >\varepsilon \right) = 0, \tag 1$$ then it does **not** follow that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr \left( \frac {S_n} n = 1 \right) = 1. \tag 2$$

Suppose $S_n = X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent and $\operatorname{E}X_n = 1$ for every $n,$ and $\operatorname{var}X_n = \sigma^2 < \infty$ for every $n.$ Then $(1)$ holds. But if the distributions of $X_n$ are all the same and it is a continuous distirbution, then $(2)$ does not hold, because $S_n/n$ also has a continuous distribution, and the probability that a continuously distributed random variable is equal to a particular number is $0.$

Comment: Yes, it truly equals 0 if $ S_n $ is continuously distributed. But what if         
 $ {S_n} \in {1,2... n(n+1)} $ ?